# Highstocks 1M Zoom not active

Tags: highcharts

There's probably a simple answer for this. I have a basic columnRange chart with high/low data points for a range of dates from May 20th to Aug 26th but the "1M" zoom is not active. It seems like this should be available. I can understand why the 6M and 1Y are not available to select but a little confused on the 1M. Am I overlooking something? I'm fairly new to highcharts. Thanks for any feedback.

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bun72/)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<title>Zoom Test</title>
<body> 

<script>
$(function () {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {
                type: 'columnrange'
            },

                    exporting: {enabled: false},

                    legend: {
                        enabled: false,
                        itemHoverStyle: {
                        cursor: 'default'
                    }

                    }, 
                    navigator: {
                        maskFill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20)',
                    },
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 5
            },
                    xAxis:{
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                    series: [{ "dataGrouping": {"enabled": false}, "name":"Zoom Test", "data": [
                        [1369065600000,200,220],
                        [1369670400000,220,240],
                        [1370275200000,230,250],
                        [1370880000000,240,260],
                        [1371484800000,250,270],
                        [1372089600000,260,280],
                        [1372694400000,270,300],
                        [1373299200000,260,280],
                        [1373904000000,240,245],
                        [1374508800000,220,225],
                        [1375113600000,200,240],
                        [1375718400000,240,260],
                        [1376323200000,250,270],
                        [1376928000000,200,230],
                        [1377532800000,210,240]]}]
        });

});
</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width:400px; height:400px;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I advice to familair with the topic about disabling buttons: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2187

Comment: Thanks for sending the pointer to this issue. I was wondering why I didn't notice this before ... it's just been released with 1.3.5! I'm fine with the 1y and YTD not being active but disabling 1m still doesn't make complete sense to me. Would adding the xAxis parameter with min and max value be an appropriate work-around?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/Bun72/1/

What you are seeing here is range of July 22nd to August 26th. 
In this example I'm using

```
selected:0
```

which basically means 1m. **BUT** as your data do not have sample for August 22nd, highstocks is rendering nearest range of 1m depending upon the data which you have provided which comes down to the range of July 22nd to August 26th. This technically is not 1m, hence '1m' is disabled in your chart.

And look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/Bun72/2/

I have changed your data to

```
                        [1369065600000,200,220],
                        [1369670400000,220,240],
                        [1370275200000,230,250],
                        [1370880000000,240,260],
                        [1371484800000,250,270],
                        [1372089600000,260,280],
                        [1372694400000,270,300],
                        [1373299200000,260,280],
                        [1373904000000,240,245],
                        [1374508800000,220,225],
                        [1375113600000,200,240],
                        [1375718400000,240,260],
                        [1376323200000,250,270],
                        [1377522000000,200,230],
                        [1377532800000,210,240]
```

This is exactly similar to your data **but** one thing differs. The second last date `1377522000000` corresponds to aug 22nd. Now 1m is enabled and selected because data for this range is available.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying. The data I'm displaying on the chart is only collected on Mondays of every week. Does this mean the 1m zoom will not work for that? I don't have the option of changing the date for the data. --Thanks

Comment: If you are taking samples every Monday, then theoretically it should work. Check your data if it is consistent. Give it a try using more samples.